# Laravel views do not refresh

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

Working on Windows 7 with WAMP.

Changing a view code does not reflect in the browser.

I tried:

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan view:clear
3. composer dupmautoload
4. deleted everything under storage/framework/views
5. restarted the computer
6. In my php.ini the opcache is disabled:

opcache.enable=0

Nothing helps, this is very frustrating.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you working on the same folder ? where you are deleting and where it is actually pointed ?

Comment: OMG, OMG, OMG!!!!! This is so embarrassing. I copied the whole folder a few days ago, and didn't realize Netbeans decided the new folder is the project I'm working on now.... Oh dear, *blush* THANK YOU @user2486

Answer (score 0):

Oops, tired, worked on the wrong project